# Callback во фрагмент

Tags: java, android, mvp, solid

Есть активити A, фрагменты B и C.

Во фрагменте B список событий. А во фрагменте C добавление новых записей (создание на сервере).

Запускаем активити и при старте видим фрагмент В. При нажатии кнопки в тулбаре переходим в фрагмент C и создаём запись и нажимаем кнопку назад и по стеклу возвращаемся в фрагмент В.

Теперь необходимо правильно сделать механизм обновления данных в recyclerview. 
Т.е. если в фрагменте С мы что-то добавили мы при возврате во фрагмент B должны тянуть данные с сервера, а если мы просто открыли и закрыли фрагмент С то нечего при возврате на В не должно происходить.

Реализовано паттерном MVP. Используется Moxy с его ViewState'ами.
Использую репозитории внутри презентера.

Answer (score 0):

Есть масса способов реализовать данный вопрос. Если вы используете Room то правильней всего подписаться на обновления в базе фрагментом B. Во фрагменте С вы добавляете запись в базу, а фрагмент B узнаете об этом от Room'a. 
Если не юзаете  Room можете во фрагменте B в onResume - каждый раз дергать последний актуальные данные из репозитория (можно сравнивать списки что бы не перерисовывать их постоянно) - но это такое себе решение.
Можно еще использовать архитектурные компоненты и работать с LiveData - почитайте про данные компоненты.

Comment: первый и третий вариант интересны. Но я не использую LiVeData и в данный момент получаемая информация не кэшируется в базу(room) - не было необходимости.Спасибо за отклик!